# Regarding displaying the users & comments who liked my page - facebook

Tags: facebook

I have created a face book profile page for my business site. Also I provided 'like button' on my business site.

I understand that whenever a user likes my page thru my business site the data will be displayed in users profile who liked.

I would like to display the users who are all liked my page with the comments posted in my business profile page of facebook. Currently it is displaying only the total count of likes.

Is there any way to display the list with comments.

For this whether we need to use FQL or any face book application?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Likebox](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) of facebook you can display all the user they liked your business page. Aslo you can display recent activity feed of you Facebook business page. You can't display the comment from this. You can only add facebook comment box on your website using this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

I hope it will helps you. If you have any question that don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks & Regars.